# WPF tab bound to property - if no value I would like it to go to system default

Tags: wpf, vb.net, background

I have a tab that is bound to a property. I want the tab to change color under specific conditions but if those conditions are not met I would like the tab to go to the system default for a tab. I know how to change the color but not to get it to go to the system default. Any suggestions?

WPF:

```
<TabItem Header="Initial" Name="tab_1Initial" Background="{Binding Path=initialTab.tabColor}">
```

VB.NET:

```
tabColor = New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF89DE93")
```

VB.NET:

```
    Public Property tabColor As Brush
        Get
            Return _tabColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Brush)
            _tabColor = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("tabColor")
        End Set
    End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing i van think of, is using an method with a couple of if statements. When the tab condition is changed, call that method to check to what color it should be changed to.